# What is the correct name for this ILS Indicator?

Tags: landing, aircraft-systems, terminology, ils

What is the correct terminology for the name of the aircraft instrument that looks like this?

[image: guage]

Comment: Good writeup here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26031/what-are-the-differences-between-an-obs-a-cdi-a-heading-indicator-and-an-hsi

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is the course deviation indicator, or CDI.

Comment: Smashing, a quick Google and all the information on it I could ever want!

Answer (score 16):

That image is a basic representation of a [course deviation indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_deviation_indicator), as mentioned [by Steve H](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13743/65). An actual gauge would look like this:

[image]
<sup>*[Image Source](http://www.tghairportshop.com/v/vspfiles/photos/MD222-406-2.jpg)*</sup>

In your image, it shows that the aircraft needs to correct to the left and a little upwards, so that it will be on the glideslope as shown here.

[image: ILS Landing]

Comment: Am I misreading it?  It seems to indicate a little right and high, so correction is left and down? Mind you, I don't have an IR :)

Comment: The crosshair is the location you want to be in; the circle in the centre is the aircraft. So, in the image in the question, the aircraft needs to move up and left to be on the crosshair.

Comment: @Simon I'm not instrument rated either. According to my understanding, the circle is the aircraft, horizontal line is the glideslope (see the 2nd image in my answer), vertical line is localizer. You need to be *left* and *up*.

Comment: @Farhan that's correct assuming you're not flying the localizer back-course in which case it would be reverse sensing. You wouldn't generally be using the glide slope in that case though. There have been incidents attributed to unfamiliarity with instruments such as the artificial horizon, iirc russian aircraft traditionally showed the aircraft attitude rather than the position of the horizon (i.e. the exact opposite) and there might well be some old CDIs around showing the opposite of what you would expect as well.

Comment: @anaximander Maybe I need some training.  If the circle is the aircraft, is it not showing that it's low and left?

Comment: I am not allowed to comment here so I have to make an answer. Steer towards the needles! Use this memory rule and you can figure out where the GS and the plane is.

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that there are two CDIs above.  The top one shows the plane low and right, the second low and left.. although the second one is nearly centered.

Comment: @falstro - you should set the published front course when flying the LOC B/C. It should not be reverse sensing in this instance. You are correct in that you should not fly the glideslope in this instance, however

Comment: @SSummer an HSI would indeed not be, but a standard old school cdi doesn't care which course you set and will be reverse sensing on the b/c.